# Calculate the total sales for records with a character in a specific column | DAX

Tags: dax

I have my data like (table name t) -

| product | region | sales amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | North | 100 |
| B | North | 150 |
| C | North | 200 |
| A | South | 50 |
| B | South | 75 |
| C | South | 100 |
| A | East | 75 |
| B | East | 100 |
| C | East | 125 |

**What I want to do** -
search for "th" in the column region, and then calculate sales amount only for them

**What I have tried** -

```
CALCULATE(SUM(t[sales amount]), SEARCH("th", t[region], ,0)>0)
```

but its not giving correct result, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your `SEARCH` function be looking in the *region* column?

Comment: yes sorry, I changed

Comment: Works fine for me now. I take it you are using that as a **measure**, right? Or were you wanting a **Calculated Column** within your table?

Comment: just a measure, need to show the amount in a card

Comment: Well, your formula works perfectly for me now on the data you posted. Suggest you also test it on the data you posted.